# Is there a terminal command to enable Continuity - handoff on unsupported OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, continuity, hacking

It is known that Apple sometimes drops support for new features such as **Continuity** on older OS X releases or older Mac models, sometimes those new features not necessarily hardware dependent.

I've used a few terminal commands to enable hidden features on my Mac in the past, so I'd like to know if is there a Mac Terminal command or another safe workaround to enable **Continuity** feature on non supported Mac models?

I own a Mac Mini mid 2011, 8GB, Intel 2,3GHz running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a bit more than just a Terminal command, but check out [Continuity Activation Tool](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/):

> This tool makes the necessary changes to enable OS X 10.10 and 10.11 Continuity features on compatible hardware. Continuity features activated by this tool include Handoff, Instant Hotspot, and New Airdrop. Support for OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) is currently experimental and does not support dongles yet.

Answer (score 1):

Like patrix said, it's a bit more involved.

I posted a step by step process to getting handoff working in El Capitan for a 2011 Mac here:  [Handoff with 2011 Mac using El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213640/handoff-with-2011-mac-using-el-capitan)

You'll have to make sure, though, that your Mac has the right bluetooth card to do this.  Go to About My Mac and click on system report.  Click on bluetooth, and you should see an entry for Low Energy Supported...it should say yes.  If it says no, you'll have to see about getting a new bluetooth card for your Mac.  You can find the model # of the card you need in the instructions I posted.

Good luck!