# Unlock Mac without low energy bluetooth capabilities by iPhone app

Tags: macos, ios, hardware, bluetooth, touch-id

I have an old iMac (11,2) that doesn't have Bluetooth Low Energy. 
Do you know any way I can use my iPhone's Touch ID to unlock it?

All the apps I found require Bluetooth LE support.

Comment: Wouldn't adding a USB bluetooth adapter be something to get around this limitation? Ones based on Broadcom BCM20702 don't need drivers AFAIK on Yosemite and later.

Comment: Can you recommend specific model that works well on El capitan?

Comment: It really depends on the software you will be running. See https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/ for some great engineering and something you could try out. The time you invest will likely be more than the $15 cost of the hardware.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213640/handoff-with-2011-mac-using-el-capitan

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I mention all I want is to use MacID \ Tether \ any other app that let me unlock the iMac by the iPhone...

Comment: Be careful with MacID, it doesn't like it if you have any other BT device running at the same time.  I really like MacID and ran it for several months, until I got my BT headphones.  Once I added BT headphones, MacID started having problems, probably because the headphones caused fluctuations in the BT signal.  The dev was very helpful but in the end we couldn't get both the app and my headphones to play nice together.